# array of objects, object per key from an input object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm having some issues putting this code together.

```
{
name: 'bob',
age: 55,
role: 'baker'
}
```

would like to get:

```
[[name:'bob'],[age:55],[role:'baker']]
```

This is what I have:

```
function valFunct(obj) {
var values =[];
for(var key in obj){
values.push(obj[key]);
}
return values
}
```

The output is not what I want.

Comment: The output you want is not valid JavaScript. Do you want `[{name: 'bob'}, {age: 55}, {role: 'baker'}]`?

Comment: or perhaps `[[ "name", "bob" ], ["age", 55], ["role", "baker" ]]` ?

Comment: although in my experience, if you're wanting to split a perfectly good object into an array of key value pairs, you're probably doing it wrong...

Comment: this has to be the most bizarre, valid, question I've ever seen

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `[[name:'bob'],[age:55],[role:'baker']]` won't work, because the index of an array should be a number not a string. You're maybe looking for something like this:

```js
var input = {
  name: 'bob',
  age: 55,
  role: 'baker'
};

function transform(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] }
  });
}

console.log(transform(input));
```

Or do you want to transform it into object entries (like ES7 [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)):

```js
var input = {
  name: 'bob',
  age: 55,
  role: 'baker'
};

function transform(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return [key, obj[key]];
  });
}

console.log(transform(input));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var person = { first: "rafael", last: "cepeda", age: 24 };

function weird_fn(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
        var o = {};
        o[p] = obj[p];
        arr.push(o);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(weird_fn(person));
```

Output:

```
[ { first: 'rafael' }, { last: 'cepeda' }, { age: 24 } ]
```

Comment: You missed the `obj.hasOwnProperty(p)` ;)

Comment: @cyrix no he didn't - that's almost never needed in modern JS code.  No-one unsafely modifies `Object.prototype` these days, and the input is a plain object with no prototype chain anyway.

Comment: @Alnitak—yes it is, hence why *Object.keys* only returns own properties.

Comment: @Alnitak Fortunately in this particular case it's not needed. But you should always use it becausse it's not a question about modern JS. Every project with a decent jslint or tslint configuration will scream at you for not using it!

Answer (score -2):

If you just want an array of pairs, you can fix your push

```
values.push([key, obj[key]]);
```

Comment: this isn't actually wrong, _should_ the OP actually want `[[ key1, value1 ], [ key2, value2], ... ]`